# red5 mac osx installation

Tags: macos, installation, red5

I want to install red5 on my mac osx, but after draggning the red5 dmg file to Apllications, it doesnt create any folders there, like installation guide implies, only copies the red5 application. I look on the internet for any more detailed guides, but I could not find anything. Can you refer me to some documentation on this or tell me how to correct install it on mac?

Comment: double-click on the `dmg` file first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dmg file is a disk image.  If you open the dmg file, it will mount the image as an "external" disk and the actual application will be inside.  You need to drag the application to your Applications folder.

Comment: Thank you. I did it, but there is only Red5 application in the Applications. Where do all the files go? I thought there should be a folder Red5 in Applications.

Comment: Never mind, this worked for me: http://www.tcp1935.com/2009/09/installing-red5-server-09-rc1-on-mac-os.html

Answer (score 0):

The Red 5 Icon acts like folder, so Control-Click on the Red 5 logo and then on the menu option to show contents. Then you will get inside